# Mac Zoom utility which magnifies a selectable portion of the screen and can be minimized

Tags: mac, zoom

A Mac Zoom utility which magnifies a selectable portion of the screen and can be minimized.

If it cannot be minimized then the zoomed portion of the screen should be set as it is, so that i can do other work and switch back to it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the [Mac OS X Developer tools](http://developer.apple.com/technologies/tools/) there's an app called "[Pixie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Developer_Tools#Pixie)". It magnifies the portion of the screen under the cursor and can be "locked" on to a specific part of the screen. It has two sizes and can be minimized.

Comment: thanks man, i figured there must be some good utility out there as there are no third party apps like that

Comment: @Rishi: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

Im not really sure what you are asking for but the mac comes with a built in screen zoom tool its under System Preferences -> Universal Access -> Set the Zoom to ON then you the keyboard shortcut shown to zoom in and out

or

if you have a mouse with a scroll wheel hold down Control and scroll up and down and it will zoom in on the screen also.